# how to dynamically populate the files present in a svn folder so user could multiselect them in jenkins job for parametrized build

Tags: svn, jenkins

One solution is to output the list of files using svn list command in a file and then use that file for displaying the files for selection through extended choice plugin .Not sure how to get the output in a file.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Do you need to send folder contents (including directory names) to a file? Do you also need the contents from sub-directories?

Comment: windows
e.g if there are 5 folders ..I should be able to select one out of 5 directories probably and then again displaying the contents of selected folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion plugin itself comes with **List Subversion tags (and more)** parameter that you can select under **This build is parameterized**

- Give it a parameter **name**.
- Under **Repository URL**, enter the SVN repository location (not local filesystem) that contains the list of files.
- Provide credentials.
- You can leave everything else empty, and **Save**.

When you run the job, it will connect to the repo and populate the dropdown list with everything it sees at that location, including folders and files.

If you want to exclude something, play around with the **Tags filter**

Comment: Awesome . Thanks, Slav.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Using groovy command,I was able to show the files present inside the directory upon clicking build with parameters on run time.
First install extended choice parameter plugin
then select extended choice option ,select checkbox for selection and use following code after selecting groovy as source for populating the options in the form of checkbox.

def command = "svn list  --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username <> --password <>"

def proc = command.execute().text